# Which force acts on the hand and its direction in case of uniform circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, centripetal-force

[image]

Answer key:

[image]

[Note: (Please verify this in your comments) The answer key for ii is wrong,right? It has to be non-uniform as the direction of the acceleration is everchanging.]

now , for iii,

I believe that centrifugal force should not be the answer because centrifugal force acts on the body undergoing the circular motion, hence it should be the stone on which both centripetal and centrifugal forces are acting.

So does anyone have any clue about which force could be acting on the hand and its direction?

Another source (my textbook) says:
"Reaction of tension away from the centre of the circular path"

But isn't this same as the centrifugal force? Doesn't all this contradict "centrifugal force acts on the body undergoing the circular motion"?

So which is the force that acts on the hand? Tension? Reaction of tension? Centrifugal? or something just out of the box?

Comment: The acceleration is non-uniform as a vector since its direction is changing, but its magnitude is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

[(ii) is correct, the acceleration's direction changes but it's always pointed towards the center of the circle, which is the same as "radially inwards".]

For (iii), calling it "centripetal force" is not ideal, because centrifugal force is a fictitious force. But there is a reaction force, from Newton's 3rd law. Something must exert the centripetal force on the stone to keep it moving in a circular path, and that something is the tension in the string. The tension in the string also acts on your hand, so you feel that.

Where people use the term "centrifugal force", it's usually used to describe the force felt by an observer on the stone, who feels "flung outwards". But remember, centrifugal force is a fictitious force; it doesn't actually exist, it only appears to.

Comment: So which is the final force in (iii) ?

Comment: (ii) Radially inwards also changes. Agreeing to your point is as vague and awful to agreeing that the velocity's direction never changes because it is always tangential to the surface. Please recheck sir (Not trying to be rude but still)

Comment: @DarshitSharma final force in (iii) is down to terminology, everyone knows what's being referred to there. I'd use "reaction to the centripetal force" which is another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @DarshitSharma "radially inwards" does not change, the direction is well-defined. Why do you think it does? You could also say the velocity is always tangential to the direction of motion as well.

Comment: Sir do you agree that velocity's direction doesn't changes? Do you agree that uniform circular motion is not accelrated? right? This is what I am able to derive from your reasonings

Comment: @DarshitSharma yes the velocity's direction changes, if you measure it in terms of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$. But you can also describe it as "tangential to the direction of motion". In the same way "to the left of my house's front door" is a well-defined direction even though its exact direction changes as the Earth orbits the Sun (and the Sun orbits the Milky Way's center). Uniform circular motion *is* accelerated, there is an acceleration towards the center.

Comment: The centrifugal force is the fictitious outward body force acting on the stone, as reckoned by an observer in a rotating frame of reference in which the stone is at rest.